# How to open remote mysql database on windows from command prompt

Tags: mysql, database, windows

Environment:
I have a database on CentOS
The folder where it is saved is shared using SAMBA
Windows have access to the files at \\192.168.1.101\mysql\food\
MySQL-server is running on both systems

Problem:
I need to access the database on windows using mysql from CMD

Extra info:
I open mysql on CMD by running:
    C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -h localhost -u root -p
    mysql>

I can not display the table on \\192.168.1.101\mysql\food\ because is not the default folder for mysql

Question:
how can i change the default folder on mysql-windows to open my database? do I need something else to display the database? like add a user to mysql-server on centos and grant access

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "open this database"? You usually done "open" a MySQL database (or any server based RDBMS). You connect to a running server and run queries against it.

Comment: i have my database in centos (/var/lib/mysql/food/) and for the moment i'll be happy to do a simple "select * from nuts;" (nuts is a table in food database) from windows and see the info in CMD

Comment: So what's wrong with running the `mysql` command line client? The location of the actual data files is completely irrelevant for this question.

Comment: in windows i can see the database at (\\192.168.1.101\mysql\food\) can i change the default directory on mysql/windos to open the databases stored in that location? and how?

Comment: Again: you can ***not*** just "open" the files of the database. You ***have*** to use a SQL client to access it (and that requires a running server to which you can connect).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm running mysql-server on both machines (centos and Windows). Making aside all of centos, my concern is: i have a database in a net location on windows `\\192.168.1.101\something`, I start mysql on windows from CMD using `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -h localhost -u root -p`, now, how can i display the database stored in that location `use food; select * from nuts;` I know that on linux user can change mysql default directory to save/open the files, how can i achieve the same on windows?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean with "save/open files" in combination with a SQL statement. SQL statements don't save or open files. And what exactly do you mean with "display the database"? What is wrong with using a SELECT statement?

Comment: ... ok, I go to CMD and run mysql
`mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| data               |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

But I can not see in the list my database **food** because is in an unknown location for mysql (_\\192.168.1.101\something_)
how can I change the default dir in mysql  to (\\192.168.1.101\something) so I can SELECT a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can connect to a different host by running mysql -h 123.45.67.89. Please note that there are a few security implications:

1.You will have to grant yourself access. You will need to run something like `GRANT ALL on db_name.table TO user@your_ip IDENTIFIED BY 'password'.db_name, table` and your_ip can be * but beware of opening your server to hackers.

2.ou will have to open your server's firewall if you are not on the same LAN. Again, ymmv and you should be aware not to open the door to exploits.

3.You may want to use `SSL`( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option%5Fmysql%5Fssl ) and use `secure-auth`( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option%5Fmysql%5Fsecure-auth ) in order to protect your traffic and credentials.

Hope that helps.Thanks to you

Comment: Hi, I grant access but from Windows/CMD what i have to type in to open the database, sorry I only have 4 hours of mysql experience